# CDF from PDF of a function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem where I need to graph the CDF, for that I need to find the constant $c$. The formula below is a PDF:

> $f(x) = c(x^2+1)\space\space\space if\space X \in [0,1];\space$ otherwise $0$

**My attempt:**
$P(0\leq X \leq 1) = \int_0^1c*(x^2+1) = 1 \Rightarrow cx+\frac {cx^3}3 = 1 \Rightarrow c = 3/4$

The problem here is that when we put $x=1$ we get $f(1) = \frac 32 > 1$, which is wrong as probability cannot be higher than $1$. I need to construct the CDF, but because of that, I cannot do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CDF cannot exceed $1$, but the PDF can. Your CDF is $\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{1}{4}x^3$ on $[0,\,1]$, just as you calculated.

Comment: Then how can you find the CDF from the PDF?

Comment: @TigranMinasyan You basically did it already; see my edit.

Comment: Indeed. The CDF is $F(x)~{=\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\lt 1}~\int_0^x c~(s^2+1)~\mathrm d s+\mathbf 1_{1\leq x}\\= \tfrac 34(\tfrac 13x^3+x)~\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\lt 1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leq x}}$